# Django - limiting query results

Tags: django

I want to take the last 10 instances of a model and have this code:

```
 Model.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

Is it true that firstly pick up all instances, and then take only 10 last ones?
Is there any more effective method?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Answer (score 444, accepted):

Django querysets are lazy. That means a query will hit the database only when you specifically ask for the result.

So until you print or actually use the result of a query you can filter further with no database access.

As you can see below your code only executes one sql query to fetch only the last 10 items.

```
In [19]: import logging                                 
In [20]: l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')    
In [21]: l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)                      
In [22]: l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())      
In [23]: User.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]          
(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" ORDER BY "auth_user"."id" DESC LIMIT 10; args=()
Out[23]: [<User: hamdi>]
```

Comment: I tried this on mongoDB and it says SELECT not supported. How to do this on mongoDB?

Comment: @winux Since this is Django-specific, it sounds like you might need to look into setting up Django to work specifically with Mongo/NoSQL-type databases. That's not a typical setup in my experience, with regard to standard Django ORM setup.

Answer (score 65):

Actually I think the `LIMIT 10` would be issued to the database so slicing would not occur in Python but in the database.

See [limiting-querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) for more information.

Comment: Note that this won't work for querysets that also need filtering, as you cannot filter after slicing.

Comment: So filter first than slice it. Thanks Davor for link!

Answer (score 21):

Looks like the solution in the question doesn't work with Django 1.7 anymore and raises an error:
"Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken"

According to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets forcing the “step” parameter of Python slice syntax evaluates the Query. It works this way:

```py
Model.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10:1]
```

Still I wonder if the limit is executed in SQL or Python slices the whole result array returned. There is no good to retrieve huge lists to application memory.

Comment: Even this solution doesn't work with django>=1.8 tested.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. If you want to fetch a limited subset of objects, you can with the below code:

Example:

```
obj=emp.objects.all()[0:10]
```

The beginning 0 is optional, so

```
obj=emp.objects.all()[:10]
```

The above code returns the first 10 instances.

Answer (score 4):

Slicing of `QuerySets` returns a `list` which means if you do like:

```
>>> Model.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

it will return a list and the problem with that is you cannot perform further `QuerySet` methods on `list`

So if you want to do more on the returned results, you can do something like:

```
>>> limit = 5 # your choice
>>>
>>> m1 = Model.objects.filter(pk__gte=Model.objects.count() - limit) # last five
>>> m2 = Model.objects.filter(pk__lte=limit)  # first five
```

Now you can perform more methods:

```
# Just for illustration
>>> m2.annotate(Avg("some_integer_column")) # annotate
>>> m2.annotate(Sum("some_integer_column"))
>>> m2.aggregate(Sum("some_integer_column")) # aggregate
```

By using **slice** notation([]) to limit results, you may also limit the ability to [chain QuerySet methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters).

If you are pretty sure that you will not need to make any further query then slicing will do the thing.

Comment: This is a bad solution. You cant always assume your pk is numeric or is in serial... what if you have broken numbers in your primary keys or some deleted rows?

Comment: This is an incorrect solution. The usage of `lte` in this context is incorrect like @Oluwatumbi pointed out

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer for filter issue

```
Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("-id")[:limit]
```

Just put `order_by` and then `[:limit]`

Answer (score 2):

As an addition and observation to the other useful answers, it's worth noticing that actually doing  `[:10]` as slicing will return **the first 10 elements of the list**, not the last 10...

To get the last 10 you should do `[-10:]` instead (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/930397/3908170)). This will help you avoid using `order_by('-id')` with the `-` to reverse the elements.

Comment: I tried this and got "Negative indexing is not supported."

Comment: @DarkCygnus ```Product.objects.filter(~Q(price=0))[-5:]``` cause me same error: "Negative indexing is not supported."

Comment: This doesn't work in django on a queryset: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13089 If you convert the queryset to a list it will work.

Comment: @valem Converting the queryset to a list will override django's lazy evaluation and cause huge datasets to be fetched from the database

Comment: @Navaneethan yes that's true. but not really relevant to this answer

Answer (score 1):

#### **Django 1.9.1**

###### print qs.query and see **LIMIT**

[image]

```
pos_random = Position.objects.filter( gps_time__gte = start_time, gps_time__lte = end_time, vehicle = v)[:**LIMIT_NUMBER**]
```