# How to query and update some record set in django models atomically?

Tags: python, django

I have some records in a django Model, and each time I want to query and update some of them.
How can perform this operation **atomically**?

```
def queryAndUpdate(count):
    entries = Model.objects.filter(...)[:count]
    for entry in entries:
        entry.count = F('count') + 1
        entry.save()
    return entries
```

I tried **QuerySet.select_for_update()**, but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
Model.objects.filter(...).update(count=F('count') + 1)
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) is the doc.

If you want to limit the size of `QuerySet` as 100, use `Model.objects.filter(...)[:100]`. It will be translated to `SELECT ... LIMIT 100`, so you don't need to worry about the performance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574003/django-limiting-query-results) is another question about this.

And it's return value is `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`, same as `Model.objects.filter(...)`, so you can use `Model.objects.filter(...)[:100].update(...)` too.

Comment: But it cannot slice the QuerySet, and update method only return the size of the QuerySet

Comment: It not help, update method cannot use after slicing the QuerySet