# Display specific number of random items in array with For loop

Tags: python, arrays, django

I am working with a template in django trying to dispaly a specific number of random items from an array of related objects

for now i display all items in the array what changes can i make

```
 {%  for pdt in object.pdt_set.all  %}
    <div class="ps-product ps-product--simple">
            <div class="ps-product__thumbnail">
              <a href="{% url 'pdtdetail' pdt.id %}"><img src="{{ pdt.image.ur }}"alt=""></a>
              <div class="ps-product__badge">-16%</div>
              <ul class="ps-product__actions">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Read More"><i
                      class="icon-bag2"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-placement="top" title="Quick View" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#product-quickview"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to Whishlist"><i
                      class="icon-heart"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Compare"><i
                      class="icon-chart-bars"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-product__container">
              <div class="ps-product__content" data-mh="garden"><a class="ps-product__title"
                  href="product-default.html">{{ pdt.name  }}</a>
                <div class="ps-product__rating">
                  <select class="ps-rating" data-read-only="true">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="1">2</option>
                    <option value="1">3</option>
                    <option value="1">4</option>
                    <option value="2">5</option>
                  </select><span>01</span>
                </div>
                <p class="ps-product__price sale">$ {{ pdt.price }} </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using this queryset:  `{%  for pdt in object.pdt_set.all  %}`

All you have to do is randomize it and limit how many results you select

`{%  for pdt in object.pdt_set.order_by('?').limit(5)  %}`

or

`{%  for pdt in object.pdt_set.order_by('?')[:5]  %}`

Replace 5 with however many records you want

See:

[How to pull a random record using Django's ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962619/how-to-pull-a-random-record-using-djangos-orm)

[Django - limiting query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574003/django-limiting-query-results)

Comment: okay but according to those posts they say it is slow what's your take ? @AayushAgrawal

Comment: There's an old principle in programming - 'It's better to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission'

Try it. If it feels slow, don't use it. This will only be slow if pdt_set has millions or billions of records, and i have a feeling that is probably not the case here :)

Comment: been getting Could not parse the remainder: '('?')[:5]'  errors any idea

Comment: @JordanRob That's caused by Jinja2 trying to prevent function execution. If you pass the entire variable object.pdt_set.order_by('?')[:5] from the View instead of evaluating in the template it should fix the problem