# Efficient Django query filter first n records

Tags: sql, django

I'm trying to filter for the first (or last) `n` Message objects which match a certain filter. Right now I need to filter for all matches then slice.

```
def get(self, request, chat_id, n):
    last_n_messages = Message.objects.filter(chat=chat_id).order_by('-id')[:n]
    last_n_sorted = reversed(last_n_messages)
    serializer = MessageSerializer(last_n_sorted, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is clearly not efficient. Is there a way to get the first (or last) `n` items without exhaustively loading every match?

Comment: How did you solve this? as you have not marked an answer given below answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself. Basically the `[:n]` puts a SQL "LIMIT" in the query which makes the query itself NOT exhaustive. So it's fine in terms of efficiency.

Link for similar answer below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6574137/4775212

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is known, it can also be using **range**.

```
Message.objects.filter(chat__range=[chat_id, chat_id+n]).order_by('-id')
```