# How to achieve row num functionality in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need only 5th and 30th record (from top) in the below query set?

```
qs=Posts.objects.filter().orderby('-date')
```

is there any rownum functionality available in django to achieve this in a single query like rownum=5 ??.

Note: I am using Postgres

Comment: Have you checked this: [Django - limiting query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574003/django-limiting-query-results) or [Limiting Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets).
Using: [start:end]. `qs=Posts.objects.filter().orderby('-date')[5:30]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecast the queryset into a list then perform normal list indexing to get the desired results.
Just use

```
q = list(qs)
```

However this is not efficient as it may eat some memory depending on the size of the query set, so other methods you may refer - [How to convert a Django QuerySet to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list)