# how to get the index of the end string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir): 
    for i in range(0, files.index(files[-1]) + 1):
```

**`files.index(files[-1])` here is the end index of item in `files`, and I got it.**

But I want to know is there a simple way to get it?
I know if I got the end item, say, like "d", after typing in files.index("d"), I would have gotten the index.

Answer (score 2):

`files` is a list, then you can use `len()` function. So, `files.index(files[-1])` is equal to `len(files) - 1`.

Actually your question is about finding the last index. Take a look at [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889820/how-to-obtain-the-last-index-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last letter (starting from the last letter):

```
s = 'acbc'
print(s.find(s[-1], -1))
```

gives you `3`, which is the index of the last letter. 
The same you can use for your case.