# Converting a one-item list to an integer

Tags: python

I've been asked to accept a list of integers (x), add the first value and the last value in the list, and then return an integer with the sum. I've used the following code to do that, but the problem I have is that when I try to evaluate the sum it's actually a one-item list instead of an integer. I've tried to cast it to an int but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):  
    lengthOfList = len(x)  
    firstDigit = x[0:1]  
    lastDigit = x[lengthOfList:lengthOfList-1]  
    sum = firstDigit + lastDigit  
    return sum
```

Comment: What should the behavior be if `x` contains one number? Should it return `x[0]` or `2*x[0]`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Use indexes

You're slicing the list, which return lists. Here, you should use indexes instead:

```
firstDigit = x[0]
lastDigit = x[-1]
```

---

## Why is slicing wrong for you:

When you do `x[0:1]`, you're taking the **list of items** from the beginning of the list to the first interval.

```
 item0, item1, item2, item3
^ interval 0
        ^ interval 1
              ^ interval 2 
                     ^ interval 3
```

Doing `x[0:2]`, for example, would return items 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5):

It all boils down to this:

```
def addFirstAndLast(x): 
    return x[0] + x[-1]
```

In Python, a negative list index means: start indexing from the right of the list in direction to the left, where the first position from right-to-left is `-1`, the second position is `-2` and the last position is `-len(lst)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930398/2157793):

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):  
    return x[0] + x[-1]
```

**x[0]** = will give you 0<sup>th</sup> index of the list, **first value**.

**x[-1]** = will give you the **last** element of the list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just adding a special case here for anyone who is struggling like I was with list comprehensions, which return a list. @Thomas Orozco's answer saved me.  This is a dead-simple example:

```
mylist=[1,5,6]
[el for el in mylist if el==5]
>> [5] #returns a *list* containing the element -- not what I wanted
```

Adding a subscript extracts the element from the list.

```
[el for el in mylist if el==5][0]
>> 5 #returns the element itself
```

If you want multiple elements returned as a tuple (not a list), you can enclose the whole statement:
`tuple([el for el in l if (el==5 or el==6)])`