# how do i print using an f string and my variable within the string is part of a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('products', ['a'], ['b'])

def test_letters():

     assert print(f'this is the letter {products}')
```

On the output on the command line I get this

```
this is the letter ['a']
```

but I want it to be as a string and print both the letter a and b

```
this is the letter a
or 
this is the letter b
```

Comment: Do you know how to take an item from a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a one-item list to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887885/converting-a-one-item-list-to-an-integer)

Comment: So just use `products[0]`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i believe i can simply use products[0] right? but what if im using pytest and using parametrization for example: `@pytest.mark.parametrize('products', ['a'], ['b'])`

Comment: print(f'this is the letter {products[0]}') will work for printing letter 'a'

Comment: That seems like a totally different question which you didn't ask so far.

Comment: `print(f'this is the letter {products[0]}')`