# How to reinitialize list in loop iteration?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create draws without replacement, and output the result of each draw as a text file. The list is in a separate file, and I want to re-import it for each iteration of my loop

```
import random
import numberlist

counter=0
draws= 100
while (counter<draws):
    x=  numberlist.listX     #this imports a list of strings eg. ['a341','c32k','42b]]

    random.shuffle(x)     

    x.pop()
    """OPERATIONS WITH POPPED VALUE"""

    counter += 1
```

What I was hoping for was that X would be realitialized to the the complete listX at the beginning of every loop iteration. Instead what I"m finding is that every time I pop a number, the list gets smaller every loop iteration. Why is this happening, and how can I get around it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a shallow copy of the list:

```
x=  numberlist.listX[:]  #or list(numberlist.listX)
```

Using just `x=  numberlist.listX` only creates a new reference to the same object.

Example:

```
In [1]: lis=[1,2,3]

In [2]: x=lis

In [3]: x is lis  #both point to the same object
Out[3]: True

In [4]: x=lis[:]  #create a shallow copy

In [5]: x is lis 
Out[5]: False
```

I think you can replace your while loop with this:

```
for item in (random.choice(lis) for _ in xrange(draws)):
    #do something with item
```

Comment: Even better, `def listX(): return list(['a341','c32k','42b])`

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) when pop is called in a list it removes the item at the given position in the list, and return it.

Considering you are creating a new reference to the same object using

```
x= numberlist.listX
```

as said above, it is expected that the list will not have the same elements in each loop iteration.

My suggestion is to do something like:

```
import random

counter=0
draws= 100
xlist = ['a341','c32k','42b']
while (counter<draws):
    x = xlist

    random.shuffle(x)     

    print x[-1]
    """OPERATIONS WITH POPPED VALUE"""

    counter += 1
```

where

`x[-1]`

[just returns the last element of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but according to the comment above yours, your code suffers from the same problem as mine: x still references the same list, the shallow copy with the slice operator fixed it for me.