# Transforming sequence of pure characters into separate float numbers in python

Tags: python, string, transformation

I have thousands of lines with data in the form: 6580,f|S,17:42:29.3,-39:01:48,2.19,2.41,-0.22

I would like to take only the last number (in this case -0.22) so I can perform some calculations.
My problem is: the lines aren't strings, and they have variable length (slicing from the beginning/end isn't an option). How can separate those commas and create a list of strings or floats?

Is there a way to separate that sequence in way that I can use, for example, "line[6]" to get that last value?

Comment: If the lines are not strings, what are them?

Comment: What is this, a file? One big string with newline characters in it?

Comment: Sorry, the lines were strings, indeed. I just couldn't find a successful way to separate what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the floating number you need is *always* the *last entry* in comma-separated `line`, `float(line.split(',')[-1])` should  do the trick.

Otherwise I would do something like the following:

```
def isFloat(val):
    try:
        float(val)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

 number = [x for x in line.split(',') if isFloat(x)][-1]
```

If all the lines you have are stored in a text file, open it and process your lines:

```
with open("my_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Here goes the code where you're getting the floating number from the line
```

Comment: Using float(line.split(',')) solved the issue, and then I only needed a line[6] to take the last value. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're looking for this syntax line[:-1] will always give you the last element in an array.

It could possibly be line[::-1]. Somebody should correct me if I'm wrong.

BTW if they are not strings, what are they?

---

**Edit.
It's line[-1],** [Getting the last element of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list)