# How to access the final item in a list?(python)

Tags: python, list

How do you access the final item in a list without knowing how many items are in that list?

for example:

```
list_items = [0,0,0,0,....... ,2]
print (the last item in the list)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  think you just mean the last index, `[-1]` returns the last element:

```
>>> print(list_items[-1])
2
```

Indices from the end towards the start are accessed with negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
list_items[-1]
```

to access the last element.