# Can't get last column of data.frame

Tags: r

Consider the following data:

```
subjectName <- c("John Doe", "Jane Doe")
temperature <- c(98.1, 98.6)
gender <- factor(c('male', 'female'), levels = c('male','female'))

ptData <- data.frame(subjectName, temperature, gender, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

When I call:

```
ptData[,1]
```

I receive the first column, as expected.  However, when I call:

```
ptData[,-1]
```

R fails to give me the last column.  Instead, it outputs the last two:

```
  temperature gender
1        98.1   male
2        98.6 female
```

Why doesn't my call work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptData[,-1]` gives you all columns *except for the first*. Try `ptData[,ncol(ptData)]` to get the last column.

(You may be confused about rows and columns... rows are indexed by the entry *before* the comma.)

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it.  `ptData[,ncol(ptData)]` will give me the last column.  But, I am more curious as to why my code doesn't work as expected.  If `ptData[,1]` gives the me first column, then why doesn't `ptData[,-1]` give me the last?  For example, look at this vector `v <- c(1,2)`
`v[-1] # outputs 2`

Comment: @user1477388 It does work as documented. Read `help("[")` and adjust you expectations.

Comment: As @AnandaMahto explains, `foo[,c(i,j)]` will give you columns `i` and `j`... whereas `foo[,-c(i,j)]` will give you all columns *except for columns `i` and `j`* (if both `i` and `j` are positive integers). You may have misunderstood something...

Comment: @user1477388, your vector example only works because the vector has only two elements: removing the first element in that case results in only the last element being returned/left. Try the same with more than 2 elements in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

In python alist[-1] give last element but not in R. See [Getting the last element of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list)

In addition to ptData[,ncol(ptData)], one can also use length function:

to get a list:

```
> ptData[,length(ptData)]
[1] male   female
Levels: male female
```

or to get a dataframe:

```
> ptData[length(ptData)]
  gender
1   male
2 female
```