# Inserting item into list in Python, but not overwriting

Tags: python

I need to add the word 'and' to the end of my list, as in

a, b, and c

So far I've got the commas sorted out. I've seen how to get at the last item in a list here

[Getting the last element of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-python#930398)

but do not want to overwrite or replace the last item, just add a word in front of it. This is what I have so far:

```
listToPrint = []
while True:
    newWord = input('Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > ')
    if newWord == '':
        break
    else:
        listToPrint.append(newWord)
print('The list is: ' + ", ".join(listToPrint), end="")
```

As if its not too obvious, I'm fairly new to python, and this is being compiled in PyCharm.

Thanks in adv

Comment: The simplest destructive way is to change the last item to `and X`, e.g. `listToPrint[-1] = 'and ' + listToPrint[-1]` just before your `print()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative slicing for your list like this:

```
', '.join(listToPrint[:-1]) + ', and ' + listToPrint[-1]
```

With `format()` function:

```
'{}, and {}'.format(', '.join(listToPrint[:-1]), listToPrint[-1])
```

`format()` replaces the first `{}` with the value of `', '.join(listToPrint[:-1])` and the second `{}` with the value of `listToPrint[-1]`. for more details, check its documentation here [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

**Output:**

```
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > 'Hello'
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > 'SOF'
Enter a word to add to the list (press return to stop adding words) > 'Users'
# ... 
>>> print('{}, and {}'.format(', '.join(listToPrint[:-1]), listToPrint[-1]))
Hello, SOF, and Users
```

Comment: That is perfect! I new I needed negative slicing, just unaware as to how to format it. So this formats it in the way I need regardless of the size of the list. 

How does this code work:
'{}, and {}'.format
?