# Getting last element of range in Python

Tags: python, indexing, range, element

This may be an easy question, but could you tell me how I can print the last element in a range, please ? I did in this way:

```
for j in range (3):
    print(j[2:])      # I only wish to print 2 here
```

But it says

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Could you tell me how to I can get it with this range function, please ?

Comment: If you don't need a `for` loop; just use `j = range(3)` instead of `for j in range(3)`.

Comment: I need to use for loop, unfortunately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last element of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Then assign a variable before the loop, say `numbers = range(3)`; change the loop to `for j in numbers:`, and use `print(numbers[-1])`

Comment: Using a for loop makes no sense, since you don't need to iterate over the collection, you just need to get the last element.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Range returns a list counting from 0 to 2 (3 minus 1) (`[0, 1, 2]`), so you can simply access the element directly from the range element. Index `-1` refers to the last element.

```
print(range(3)[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

I the range is in your collection you should be able to reference that object directly by the index.

```
if len(j) > 2:
    print("Value: " + j[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop will go through the list and check if it is the last item, if true, then print the message underneath.

```
num_list = [28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22]
 
 for i in range(len(num_list)):

    print(num_list[i])
    if num_list[-1] == num_list[i]:
        print ('last number: ' + str(num_list[i]))`
```