# How do I print the first and last value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below part code prints all the host IP Address that lies in the Subnet, I want to modify the code so that it prints only the starting address and the last address of this list

How do I use an array here to print the first and last value?

```
import ipaddress
print('enter subnet')  # in CIDR Format
x = input()
IP= ipaddress.ip_network(x, strict = False)
for y in IP.hosts():
 print(y)
```

Current Output

```
enter subnet
192.0.0.0/29
192.0.0.1
192.0.0.2
192.0.0.3
192.0.0.4
192.0.0.5
192.0.0.6
```

Desired output

```
HostMin:   192.0.0.1  
HostMax:   192.0.0.6
```

=========================================

## UPDATE:

After using the list i was able to print the first and last values

```
however this takes quite longer to compute whenever i give a large
subnet

like 192.0.0.0/8 takes longer to print the first and last value, 

for: IPV6 address calculations it hangs forever, 
for: example: the  IPV6 address is 2001:db8::1/96 

this list will have 4294967294 elements since this IPV6 subnet has
these many IP address and it hangs forever to print the first and
last element of the list
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list[0]` and `list[-1]` gets you the first and last element respectively

```
import ipaddress
print('enter subnet')  # in CIDR Format
x = input()
IP= ipaddress.ip_network(x, strict = False)
k = list(IP.hosts())
print("HostMin: ",k[0])
print("HostMax: ",k[-1])
```

Updated Answer for getting first and last IP without generating the whole IP range

```
import ipaddress
def hosts(IPTYPE):
    """Custom function derived from IPv6Network/IPv4Network.hosts to get only first and last host

    """
    network = int(IPTYPE.network_address)
    broadcast = int(IPTYPE.broadcast_address)
    return IPTYPE._address_class(network+1),IPTYPE._address_class(broadcast)

print('enter subnet')  # in CIDR Format
x = input()
IP= ipaddress.ip_network(x, strict = False)
m = hosts(IP)
print("HostMin: ",m[0])
print("HostMax: ",m[1])
```

Comment: however this takes quite longer to compute whenever i give a large subnet, like 192.0.0.0/8 takes longer to print the first and last value,                               and for IPV6 address calculations it hangs forever, for example if i enter the IPV6 address as 2001:db8::1/96 it has 4294967294 elements and it hangs to print the first and last element of the list

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a custom method derived from ipaddress module which gives only the first and last IP instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

replace `for y in IP.hosts():` by `y = list(IP.hosts())` and then you can do

```
print y[0]
print y[-1]
```

You should read the doc of [hosts()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) function "Returns an iterator over the usable hosts in the network"

Comment: this takes quite longer to compute whenever i give a large subnet, like 192.0.0.0/8 takes longer to print the first and last value, and for IPV6 address calculations it hangs forever, for example if i enter the IPV6 address as 2001:db8::1/96 it has 4294967294 elements and it hangs to print the first and last element of the list

Answer (score 0):

You don't use an array here. Use a list!

```
first_item = list[0]
last_item = list[-1]
```