# Accessing last item in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have code which produces a list of lists for example something like

```
import numpy as np
list=np.linspace(0,100,num=100)
n=100
for j in range(2,n):
        samples=[]
        for i in range(1,j): 
            samples.append(list[i])  
        print(samples)
```

Which produces output like the following:

```
[0,1]
[0,1,2]
[0,1,2,3]
.
.
.
[0,1,2,...,100]
```

How do I amend my code so that it only returns the last list in the output which would be the list [0,1,2,...,100]?

Comment: print(samples[-1]) after loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last element of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Using negative indices like -1 (last element):

```
import numpy as np
list=np.linspace(0,100,num=100)
n=100
for j in range(2,n):
        samples=[]
        for i in range(1,j): 
            samples.append(list[i])  
        print(samples[-1])
```