# General question about the significance of -1

Tags: python, image, scipy, shift

I'm working on a problem in a machine learning and I see [-1] popping up somewhat frequently in difference places of the code but I can't seem to understand the significance of it.

In this particular example, the goal is to slightly shift all images in the training set.

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

def shift_image(image, dx, dy):
    image = image.reshape((28, 28))
    shifted_image = shift(image, [dy, dx], cval=0, mode="constant")
    return shifted_image.reshape([-1])
```

What is the significance of the -1 in the last line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last element of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: It's [explicitly documented](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)....

Comment: `[12]` is a list containing one element: `12`. Same for your minus one value (cannot type it, SO prevents it)

Comment: Both of those dupes are very wrong

Comment: @JETM that's wrong...

Comment: "The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions."

Comment: From the docs "One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions." In general `-1` can have different special meanings: the last item as an index, no value as seen above, negative result in `string.find()`...

Comment: To be more specific: `shifted_image.reshape([-1])` flattens the 2-d image into a 1-d array.  A more "numpythonic" way to do that is `shifted_image.ravel()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numpy arrays, [`reshape`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) Allows you to "infer" one of the dimensions when trying to reshape an array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
#Output:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
a.reshape([-1])
#Output:
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

If you notice, you can also rewrite the first reshape using inference as follows:

```
b =np.arange(4).reshape(2,-1)
#Output:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: My goodness, the number of incorrect dupes and answers thrown about on this question! I'm on my phone so couldn't answer, thankfully we got there :)

Comment: Haha, well, better late than never eh? I'm a slow typer i'm afraid. Oh well!

Comment: Aha! Pretty new to programming so I'm still learning the ropes when it comes to reading through the documentation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
shifted_image.reshape([-1])
```

Is simply calling the [`reshape`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) method with a list as parameter, and the list happens to contain a single element, the number `-1`. This has the effect of reshaping the numpy array. From the docs:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions

Comment: This doesn't explain at all what it _does_, though