# How to grep in python the last line?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
with open('gauss.log', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
     if line.__contains__('SCF Done'):
       print(line.split()[4])
```

now my problem is that I got something like, output:

```
-966.460358542
-966.462639325
-966.462959240
-966.463091939
-966.463234242
-966.463376736
-966.463488664
-966.463497061
-966.463527583
-966.463547506
-966.463549649
-966.463566858
-966.463575344
-966.463585840
-966.463589645
-966.463596480
-966.463602018
-966.463606042
-966.463607554
-966.463608071
-966.463608088
```

but I need only the last number of the last SCF Done cycle, how I can correct my script? I want just to grep the last SCF Done, like the "tail -1" option.

Comment: Don't do this: `line.__contains__` use `in`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to [loop backwards over the lines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) and get the first match then stop searching (saves time, saves space):

```
for line in reversed(lines):    #   reversed : the name explains it all
    if 'SCF Done' in line:      #   found one while searching backwards
        print(line.split()[4])  #   print the number
        break                   #   stop searching
```

Answer (score 0):

Save only the most recent one.  When you run out of lines, print that one alone.  Your `print` has to be *outside* of the loop.

```
for line in lines:
    if 'SCF Done' in line:
        last = line.split()[4]

print(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient answer posted is by MrGeek.

**Below is a less efficient method, but is a useful look at filters - in case you wish to further process your full data set, and keep a list of all of your `SCF Done` values:**

Read in your lines like you did before:

`with open('gauss.log', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()`

Then [filter them](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) for all lines containing only `SCF Done`:

`filteredLines = list(filter(lambda line: 'SCF Done' in line, lines))`

Then [take the last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list) of your filteredLines:

`print(filteredLines[-1])`