# Find the last file name in python

Tags: python

I have same file name eg: filename1, filename2 , filename3, filename4 ..... filename10

I want to find last file of that specific name
over here last file name is filename10

```
import os
import datetime
import re

files = []
for file in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Mayur Pawar\\Desktop\\FTP work"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        files.append(file)
#s = sorted(files)

#print(files)

sorted(files)
```

Comment: Do you want to sort them alphabetically and then display the last one?

Comment: Sorting alphabetically will give you for example, `filename1`, `filename10`, `filename2`... You need to sort according to the number **as a number**, not as string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the last element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Comment: One problem is that "sorted" returns a new list. You can try "files.sort()" instead.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the built-in function `max`:

```
import re

last_file = max(files, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))
```

Comment: example: list = [abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4,efg1,efg2,efg3,efg4,efg5]

Comment: in above list i want to find the last filename. in abc last file is abc4 and efg5

Comment: Seems like you want the last 2 or?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex to do this. Not the most beautiful code ever, but it works. However, if filename has other number, you may need a more complex regex:

```py
import re

files = ["filename10", "filename2", "fileename3"]

highest = 0
filename = ""
for f in files:
    dd = re.search(r'\d+', f)
    filenumber = int(dd.group())
    if filenumber > highest:
        highest = filenumber
        filename = f
```