# update a variable in a web app with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, server, arduino

I have an arduino program and set-up which detects the number of cars from a parking lot. The number of cars is printed on the serial every time when the sensor detects a car in front of the barrier.
I want to print the number of cars from the parking lot into a small web app. I use Tera Term to scan my serial bus and put the output data into a file text ( data.txt) . Then i use python to read the value from that text file and render it into a HTML page on a web app.

Here is the python code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import logging
import requests


# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Define a route for the default URL, which loads the form
@app.route("/")
def form():
 with open('date.txt') as f:
     data = []
     lines = f.read().splitlines()
     data.append(lines)
 for i in data:
     return render_template('index.html', variable=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run()
```

here is index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Arduino Project</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background: antiquewhite;
        }
h1 {color:red;
text-align: center;}
h2 {color:blue;
   text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> - Arduino - </h1>
<h2> Number of cars in the parking place: {{ variable }}<br></h2>
<script> setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine, but i want to have only a variable which updates every 5 seconds,when the page is refreshed.I dont want to see all values from the date.txt,just the last one.

This is how my web app looks like with this code until now :
(ignore the error message)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOAo8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning multiples times is not possible.

> A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call
>   and “returns” the result (value of the expression following the return
>   keyword) to the caller. The statements after the return statements are
>   not executed.

So this part could be adjusted:

```
 for i in data:
     return render_template('index.html', variable=data)
```

You said you want the last line only. So replace above with this:

```
  return render_template('index.html', variable=data[-1])
```

**Documentation**

[Getting the last element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/

Comment: Tried to replace that. I get the same output. I think the problem is with render_template() function. It always renders the same html page and adds the value next to the older one.

Comment: The same output as before or always the same once loaded?

Comment: Same  as before. For now i have a dummy project running in arduino. It counts to 1000,and prints the index every 5 seconds. So the final output is 0, 1, 2, .... 1000 and I get all these values printed into the web app. I want just the last value. Like 1, then replace it with 2, then replace it with 3 and so on.

Comment: I see what's wrong now. You have a list with 1 value. A string with all the values. You should split this string into a list. Then only give the last element as given in the answer.

Comment: Done,thank you for your answer. It was very helpful. Now it works exactly how i wanted :D