# I have a list of chemical elements but the elements with two letters are separated as well, how do i join them?

Tags: python, list, join, append, element

I want my list to have chemical elements like ['K', 'Ca', 'Fe'] but when I run my code I get ['K', 'C', 'a', 'F', 'e']. How do i fix this?

```
character_list = []
  for char in compound_formula:
     if char.isalpha():
        character_list.append(char)
```

Thank you! I am a beginner so I would need the code to be as simple as possible also a little explanation would be very helpful!

Here are some examples to test the code, compound_formula could be Fe6Cr1 or C6H2 for example.

```
>>>molform("Fe6Cr1")
['Fe','Cr']
>>>molform("C6H2")
['C','H']
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show what the original `compound_formula` looked like?

Comment: Here are examples you can use! >>>molform("C2H6O1") 
    {'C':2, 'H':6, 'O':1}   
    >>>molform("C1H4")   
    {'C':1, 'H':4}. >>>molform("Fe6Cr1")

Comment: compound_formula = "Fe6Cr1" 


character_list = []
temp_str = ""
for char in compound_formula:
    
    if char.isalpha():
        temp_str += char 
        
    else:
        character_list.append(temp_str)
        temp_str = ""

Comment: From what still remains from my year of chemistry, I would guess you need to split the elements based on a capital letter, because you might encounter things like `ROCOOR` at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can also be solved using regex.

```
import re
def get_elements(compound):
  pattern = r"([A-Z][a-z]*)[0-9]*"
  elements = re.findall(pattern,compound)
  return list(set(elements))
```

**Pattern: "([A-Z][a-z]*)[0-9]*"** 
**[A-Z]** looks for the capital letter to identify start of the element. 
*Example: F from Fe*
**[a-z]*** looks for other non-capital letters if present, to identify remaining letters of the element. 
*Example: e from Fe* 
**[0-9]*** looks for quantity of the element. 
*Example: 6 from Fe6*
**()** captures the element only, in order to discard the quantities. 
*Example: Fe from Fe6*

Here are the results:

```
print(get_elements("Fe6Cr1"))
['Fe', 'Cr']
print(get_elements("CH3COOH"))
['H', 'C', 'O']
print(get_elements("C6H2"))
['H', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR;

This is a possible solution to your use case:

```py
character_list = []
for char in compound_formula:
  if char.isupper():
    character_list.append(char)
  elif char.isalpha() and len(character_list) == 0:
    print 'Unexpected character {} in {}' format(char, compound_formula) 
  elif char.isalpha():
    character_list[-1] += char
print str(list(set(character_list)))
```

---

Not really knowing what is in your `compound_formula` but still remembering some of my year in chemistry, I would guess you might find some more complex formula where you will have, for example `C`arbon and `O`xygen elements next to each other.

More precisely, if I feed [`CH3COOH` Acetic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetic_acid) in a simple logic based on the fact that `char` is a letter won't work.

This said, you might be able to cope with that testing if the letter is in capital, using [`isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper).

Also note that the line

```py
character_list[-1] += char
```

Is actually a concatenation of the current character to the [last element of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930398/2123530), in case we meet, for example, a `e` right after a `F` so the last element would become `Fe`.

```py
character_list = []
for char in compound_formula:
  if char.isupper():
    character_list.append(char)
  elif char.isalpha() and len(character_list) == 0:
    print 'Unexpected character {} in {}' format(char, compound_formula) 
  elif char.isalpha():
    character_list[-1] += char
print str(character_list)
```

Here are some runs of it:

```
python chemistry.py Fe6Cr1
['Fe', 'Cr']
python chemistry.py C6H2 
['C', 'H']
python chemistry.py CH3COOH
['C', 'H', 'C', 'O', 'O', 'H']
```

Now looking at the last result, maybe you even want a list with [unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27305828/2123530), which can be done editing the last line to

```py
print str(list(set(character_list)))
```

With this modification, the last run now gives

```
python chemistry.py CH3COOH
['H', 'C', 'O']
```