# find minimum value of list in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, min

I've been stuck for hours please help me find a way to compare the keys in the queue to dictionary and finding the minimum value.

Below is the code I have so far. I try using min() but it doesnt work.

```
def find_min(label,queue): 
  
  for i in queue:
    for l in label:
      for s in label[i]:
        list1 = []
        return min(l[1])
```

bellow is the label and queue input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: no it doesnt I know how to sort a dictionary by value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following.

**Code**

```
def find_min(labels, queue):
    # Sort labels dictionary  based upon last item in values list 
    # which will be a number (kv[1] is value list, kv[1][-1] is last value in list)
    sorted_labels = dict(sorted(labels.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1][-1]))
    
    #  Get the keys in order from sorted_labels that are also in the queue
    options = [k for k in sorted_labels if k in queue]
    
    # Return the first one (will be the smallest)
    return options[0] if options else None
```

**Test**

```
print(find_min({"A" : [0], "B" : ["A",10], "C" : ["B",10], "D" : ["C",15]}, ["A", "D"]))  
# Output: A

print(find_min({"A" : [0], "B" : ["A",10], "C" : ["B",10], "D" : ["C",15]}, ["B", "C", "D"]))  
# Output: B
```

**Simpler Alternative**

```
def find_min(labels, queue):
    # Initialize min value
    k_min, v_min = None, None

    for k, v in labels.items():
        if k in queue:
            # Only check keys in queue
            if v_min is None or v[-1] < v_min:
                # Don't have a min yet, or less than current min
                v_min = v[-1]
                k_min = k
    return k_min
```

**Test**

```
print(find_min({"A" : [0], "B" : ["A",10], "C" : ["B",10], "D" : ["C",15]}, ["A", "D"]))  
# Output: A

print(find_min({"A" : [0], "B" : ["A",10], "C" : ["B",10], "D" : ["C",15]}, ["B", "C", "D"]))  
# Output: B
```

**Using Poster's Code**

```
def find_min(label,queue): 
    kmin = None
    value_min = None
    for l in label:
      if l in queue:
        value = label[l]
        n = len(value)
        last_value = value[n-1]
        if kmin is None or last_value < value_min:
            kmin = l
            value_min = last_value
    return kmin
```

Comment: thank you, the way you did it with lambda is too advance for me right now. Is there any way to do it in the way I was doing it above?

Comment: @JosueNunez--Hi Josue.  When you mentioned "I know how to sort a dictionary by value", I thought this meant you where familiar with using lambda expressions for the sort key (i.e. customary method).  Would it help if I used a regular function for the key or is a key function in general out?

Comment: @JosueNunez--never mind--thought of a simpler alternative.

Comment: simpler alternative would be awesome

Comment: @JosueNunez--added an alternative.  Does it make sense?

Comment: what is the v[-1] for/ signify

Comment: @JosueNunez--in general it is the last item in a list.  In your case the list is either 1 or 2 elements, but in either case we want the last element.  `v[-1]` thus provides an easy way of denoting the last element without worrying about the length.  Otherwise you would have to have v[1] when the list is one element or v[2] when the list has two elements.  Checkout [last element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/getting-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Comment: that makes perfect sense thank you

Comment: @JosueNunez--added another solution that attempts to use your posted code (i.e. minimal modification).

Comment: I get this error : if l in queue
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax      also when I fit it by putting a colon after queue the result is -> 15 15  not "A" "B"

Comment: @JosueNunez--fixed.  Sloppy error on my part.  Must be time to sleep.