# Print Latest element of list with out indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, element

```
Colors = ["yellow", "red", "green"]
```

I'm looking for new way to given the latest element of list. Is there a way without using of index `[-1]`?

Comment: You should probably giving a bit of context.  Would `Colors[3]` be a valid answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list this has a lot of nice examples

Comment: I'm looking for a way with out indexing.

Comment: I think your `Colors` needs a bit of [`pop`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop)

Comment: why tho? in any case you can do `next(reversed(my_list))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing more context would help, as you could simply use `Colors[len(Colors) - 1]`, but that still uses indexing. Another solution would be `Colors.pop()`, but keep in mind it will remove the last element.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) list:

```
next(reversed(Colors))
# 'green'
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, list class provides a function `pop()`,
You can use `Colors.pop()`

Comment: But that changes/mutates the list.

Comment: @user2390182 yes it does maybe he can create a copy of the list first or he can use your solution too

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
last = None
for x in Colors:
    last = x
print last
```

Comment: in this case the variable x isn't really necessary, you can do `for last in Colors: pass` for the same effect, but I guess is alright for extra clarity...