# Python - Get the second latest file from a file pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I have a list of files that match a particular pattern from which I need to get the latest and the second latest file paths.

I am able to get the latest file using the code below

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/home/yash/proj_dir/reference_data/*/FeaturesV3.txt')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

Is there a way to get the second latest file from the above file pattern?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Just updated it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort `list_of_files`, then use index `[-2]`, to get the second last item:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('/tmp/*.json')
latest_file = sorted(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file[-2])
```

Comment: Yeah, That did the job.