# Sorted by two values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of lists:

```py
l = [
    ["I", 2, 3],
    ["You" 3, 2],
]
```

How can i sort that in terms of max second element and min of third?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your list. If it is:

`l = [["I",2,3],["You",3,2]]`

you can do the following:

```
l.sort(key = lambda lst:(-lst[1],lst[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [
    ["I", 2, 3],
    ["You", 3, 2]
]

# The sorted() function returns a sorted list of the specified iterable object.
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) # False will sort ascending, True will sort descending. Default is False.
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[2])

print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question may be of use to you [How do I get the last element of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-do-i-get-the-last-element-of-a-list)

```
l = [['I', '2', '3'],['You' '3', '2']]

first_item = l[0][0]
last_item = l[-1][-1]
```

this is how you would access the very first element and very last element in a nested list. I am not sure what you mean by **"sort that in terms of max second element and min of third?"**