# last = list[len(list)] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = len(l)
last = l[x]
print(last)
```

I want to print last element of the list but its showing error.

Comment: l[x-1] will print last element. Len returns 6, but index starts from 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the last element of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-do-i-get-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use indexing to get the last element of the list.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(l[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`python` start counting elements at zero, so last element is len(l) *minus one* that is your code after repair is

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = len(l) - 1
last = l[x]
print(last)
```

however you might use negative index to be more concise that is do

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
last = l[-1]
print(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that python indexing starts at 0 (first element = 0), and to calculate the `n`th position in python, you do `n`-1, so you need to do `len(l) - 1`:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = len(l) - 1
last = l[x]
print(last) # 6
```

But if you use negative indexing, it starts from the end, which makes getting the last element quicker and more efficient:

```py
x = -1
last = l[x]
print(last) # 6
```