# deleting the lastly appended value from list

Tags: python, list

How can I delete the last value I appended to a list in python? For example, if a list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], I want to only delete the 5 but instead of saying list.remove(5) I want to say delete the last value I added to the list. This way I'll be able to delete the values according to the order, not what the actual value is.

I think I have to put whatever 'lastly appended value' in the parenthesis in list.remove(), but I don't know what to call the lastly appended value :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the last element of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930397/how-do-i-get-the-last-element-of-a-list)

Comment: What are you trying to do by removing the last item? This looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

list.pop()

to remove the last element.

Time Complexity: O(1)
Auxiliary Space: O(1)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `list.remove(5)` is a bad way to do it -- what if `5` appears somewhere else in the list other than just the end.

One way is to use [`list.pop()` which removes (and returns) the last element of a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Another way is to use the [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) combined with the fact that you can use the `-1` index to refer to the last element of a list:

```py
>>> mylist = [1,7,9,3,5,7,5]
>>> del mylist[-1]
>>> print(mylist)
[1,7,9,3,5,7]
```

p.s. don't call your list `list` since that name is used by python...