# Why Scapy changes last bytes?

Tags: python, tcp, wireshark, scapy

Here's a small program, that sniffs traffic with TCP dst port 5555. TCP data contains a binary file.

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, TCP, Ether, NoPayload

ba = bytearray()


def packet_handler(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(TCP):
        tcp_packet = packet[TCP]
        if tcp_packet.sport == 5555:
            # print(tcp_packet.flags)
            if tcp_packet.flags == 'PA':
                data = tcp_packet.payload
                ba.extend(bytes(data))


pkts = scapy.sniff(filter="tcp",  # and src port 5555
                   timeout=5,
                   prn=packet_handler,
                   iface="Software Loopback Interface 1")


with open('test.bin', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(bytes(ba))
```

But every time, the last few segments contain several (0-4) bad bytes.
Source file:
[image: source file]

Wireshark:
[image: wireshark]

Terminal:
[image: terminal]

At first I thought it was a problem with bytes(),
but in the picture above you can see output of scapy raw TCP data.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this situation more robustly, you should reconstruct the TCP stream and then extract the data.

TCP packets can be fragmented, and you may not be receiving the complete file in a single packet. Incomplete fragments could result in the last few bytes being incorrect.

put before your with statement:

```
# Extracting only the data from the TCP payload
data = bytes(ba).split(b'\r\n\r\n')[1]
```

script assumes that your binary file is sent after a double CRLF (b'\r\n\r\n') in the TCP payload. Adjust this accordingly based on the actual structure of your data.

Comment: also check this question for better understanding of how to get rid of last element in python https://stackoverflow.com/q/930397/16888689 , maybe you can delete last 4 byte

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The file being transferred is large enough to be fragmented. I'm trying to put it back together. But I don't understand, why scapy changes the last bytes, but Wireshark doesn't?

Comment: I looked it up.  Wireshark is a packet analyzer that operates at a lower level, capturing and displaying raw packets directly from the network.

On the other hand, Scapy is a Python library that provides a higher-level abstraction for working with packets. When you access the payload attribute of a Scapy packet, it might interpret the data in a certain way, and the representation of that data may not be exactly the same as what Wireshark displays.

Comment: In your specific case, when you extend the bytearray with bytes(data), Scapy might be doing some interpretation or processing that results in differences, especially when dealing with fragmented or incomplete data.

Comment: This is exactly what I was talking about. So what can I do about it?